# Dockerfile: Is my placement of EXPOSE correct?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm stumped by a question I received when working on an [opensource Dockerfile](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/pull/96), which boils down to, "why did you change the layers?" - so I'm trying to answer that with my own investigation.

I apologize that the subject is not well defined, but essentially it's about how docker layers relate to the docker-cache.

So I'm looking for an elegant explanation in an area which isn't well documented.

My changes from the original Dockerfile where to separate ENV into different layers, move a COPY earlier, and to expose the port later.

The original (simplified):

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
EXPOSE 80
ENV HELLO world \
    && DOCKER whale
RUN # Run stuff
COPY source /to/container
CMD # Do stuff
```

My changes:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV HELLO world  
ENV DOCKER whale   # <-- Separate ENV into different layers
COPY source /to/container   # <-- Less prone to change, move earlier
RUN # Run stuff
EXPOSE 80          # <-- "Bake in" port later
CMD # Do stuff
```

### Presumption

It's my understanding that, from a docker-cache perspective, ***separating the ENV variables into different layers is a good practice because*** -- if a user wants to override an ENV -- ***only one ENV needs to change within it's own layer***, instead of altering the entire layer which contains all the ENVs for the sake of one.

But adding the port EXPOSE later - it just feels right. This is because I've used Docker for about 18 months, and nearly all of Docker's docs and guides expose the port later in the Dockerfile.

I'm also led to believe this based upon my experience (and attending DockerCon2017 and participating some "best practice" classes) ***that layers more prone to changes/overrides should be placed later in a Dockerfile***, to better optimize the docker-cache so there aren't so many low-level layer variations.

## Question:

Is my belief correct (or foolish) assuming that separating ENV layers, moving COPY earlier, and ***placing EXPOSE layers later*** is good practice and is an overall improvement upon the original Dockerfile's layers from the perspective of optimizing the Docker cache?

Comment: Difficult to comment without knowing the full details. What is `RUN stuff` and where are the `ENV` vars used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this question has some heavily opinionated possible answers, I'll attempt to keep to facts and other things sourced from [docker's docs on this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Proper layering of layers in docker has essentially three goals (roughly ordered):

1. correctness: some things need to be combined / ordered for correctness (for example `apt` operations should always start with `apt-get update && ...` and `apt-get update` should never be in a separate `RUN` layer
2. minimize layers: fewer layers generally means better performance both for build and runtime.  This generally means combining layers when possible
3. cache performance: push cacheable layers as high up in the file as possible, note that if a layer is invalidated **all layers after that layer are also invalidated**

Given that, here's some observations from the things you've proposed:

#### separating `ENV` layers

Given (2) above, you should keep `ENV` layers combined when possible.  Users can override `--env` at runtime which does not affect build-time layering.  Yes if one of the `ENV` lines were modified in source it would invalidate the rest of the file (3) but generally this is traded off for *performance* reasons.

#### moving `COPY` up

generally this is not a good idea, the source on disk is among the *most likely* things to change, if the source changes, all the layers from the `COPY` layer downwards are invalidated

#### moving `EXPOSE`

This really doesn't matter.  `EXPOSE` is a nearly-trivial layer (it in fact does nothing unless you're linking containers).  Since it is cacheable, I'd put it near the top but again, it's trivial to compute and doesn't really change.

#### summary

tl;dr The maintainer is correct in saying no to all three changes as it will make build and run performance worse.

Comment: I like this answer! Thanks for explaining this well. I'm going to wait to accept for a bit to see if someone else would like to leave an answer. (Though I think yours is difficult to top.)